# Tensorflow eager execution 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: tensorflow

I am going through the tutorial about TensorFlow Eager Execution from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/g3doc/guide.md)

```
# Third order derivative.
d3f = tfe.gradients_function(lambda x: d2f(x)[0])
print(d3f(3.))
assert 0 == d3f(9.)[0].numpy()
```

output:

```
[None]
```

And it produces

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Why the print is different from that of tutorial. How am I supposed to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a bug in documentation: the gradient of a constant is `None` instead of `0`

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in the doc. The `d3f()` returns `None` type.

Comment: Yup, that is a bug in the documentation. The reason it produces `None` instead of `0` has some history in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783

Comment: Seems like the doc bug is not fixed. https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager has `gradgradgrad(3.)  # => [None]` line